# Writing a program that displays the number of observations from A-Z without distinguishing between lowercase and uppercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that imports from IDLE 'import this'. I want to print the number of letters from the text(The program should not distinguish between Lowercase and Uppercase)
ex. "Hello world" --> [h= 1, e= 1, l= 3...]

This is what I found when searching for a solution

```
from collections import Counter
  

test_str = '''
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
'''
  

res = Counter(test_str)

print ("The characters are:\n "
                                           +  str(res))
```

Unfortunately, this count distinguishes between lower cases and upper cases, does anyone have a better idea?

The code from above prints this:

The characters are:

```
 Counter({' ': 124, 'e': 90, 't': 76, 'i': 50, 'a': 50, 'o': 43, 's': 43, 'n': 40, 'l': 33, 'r': 32, 'h': 31, '\n': 22, 'b': 20, 'u': 20, 'p': 20, '.': 18, 'y': 17, 'm': 16, 'c': 16, 'd': 16, 'f': 11, 'g': 11, 'x': 6, '-': 6, 'v': 5, ',': 4, "'": 4, 'w': 4, 'T': 3, 'S': 3, 'A': 3, 'I': 3, 'P': 2, 'E': 2, 'k': 2, 'N': 2, '*': 2, 'Z': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'F': 1, 'R': 1, 'U': 1, 'D': 1, '!': 1})
```

Comment: Why not create your own solution rather than searching online for a solution to your homework problem?

Comment: I already have a solution using loops, ifs and importing string, but isn't this way too complicated? So i went to the web to look for a simpler answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test_str.lower()`.
Also, you can count without importing Counter, using `len()`

Comment: Or `test_str.upper()`, works the same :-D

Comment: Lol, true dat...